# Javascript - href action executes on linked page

Tags: javascript, php, href

We're using a custom built eCommerce CMS that uses:

```
<a href="javascript:AddToBasket(3471412104801);">Add to Cart</a>
```

...to add a product to the cart (let's call it Site A). We're building a seperate site (Site B) for one of our products, and I need to come up with a way to link the 'Order' button on Site B so that it calls the above javascript function once Site A loads, using that product ID.

Something along the lines of the following psuedo-code:

```
<a href="http://example.com/success#javascript:AddToBasket(3471412104801);">
    Add To Cart
</a>
```

I'm basing that on how HTML anchor links work, but I'm sure it can't be as easy as that.... Right?

I've come across solutions that relate to 'injections', which I don't have much experience in, but the general sentiment seems to be negative, citing security issues and hacking as the main problems. This may sound silly, but both websites are ours, and we control them. If we need to add something the Success page on Site A, that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to open `http://example.com/success` within your `AddToBasket()` function:

```js
function AddToBasket(id) {
    window.open('http://example.com/success', '_blank');

    ...
}
```

The downside of this is that the JavaScript isn't executed after your other page opens, but rather your page opens during the execution of your JavaScript.

Comment: The AddToBasket function is on the Site A server though, and we can't edit that particular JS file. If we do, we'll have to pay a hefty sum to the developer, which we're trying to avoid!

Comment: @tristanojbacon if the web worked in such a way that we could link people to other websites *and* make them fire their own JavaScript functions it would be incredibly insecure and everyone would avoid clicking on hyperlinks. You'd have to alter the code on Site A. You could allow Site A to fire the JavaScript function if a certain query string parameter was present, for example, but otherwise you won't be able to do this through modifications to Site B alone.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this helps but you can use the onclick attribute on the anchor.

```
     <a href="fallbackurl" onclick="AddToBasket(3471412104801);">Add to Cart</a>
```

When you click the anchor it will trigger the function.